# AngularJS not showing data in view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I stuck with the angularjs data display in view.

I got correct data in angular controller. but it is not binding in HTML.

All things are corencct.

```
  <div class="well well-sm well-light">
        <h4 class="txt-color-blue">Assembly Status <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a></h4>
        <br>
        <div class="custom-scroll table-responsive" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
            <table id="assemblystatustbl" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></i>Status Name</th>
                        <th>#Assembly</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="val in Summary">
                        <td>{{ val.Description }}</td>

                        <td>{{ val.AssemblyCount }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>
```

[image: Displays this. not angular array]

First time It works good, but when i call view via ajax got this problem

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var controllerId = 'DashBoardController';

// TODO: replace app with your module name
angular.module('CalcQouteModule').controller(controllerId,
   ['$scope', '$modal', '$routeParams', '$http', '$route', '$timeout', 'DashBoardFactory', DashBoardController]);



function DashBoardController($scope, $modal, $routeParams, $http, $route, $timeout, DashBoardFactory) {

    $scope.title = 'DashBoardController';
    $scope.activate = activate;
    $scope.Summary = [];
    activate();

    function activate() {
        DashBoardFactory.getSummary()
            .then(
            function (data) {
                console.log(data.data);
                $scope.Summary = data.data.collection;
                //angular.copy(data.data.collection, $scope.Summary);
            }, function (e) {alert(e.stautsText);});
    }
}
```

RouteConfig File

```
   .when('/DashBoard', {
             templateUrl: '/DashBoard',
             controller: 'DashBoardController'
         })
```

loading partialview

```
 $('.clk-Menu').on('click', function (event, param) {

            var link = '/DashBoard'


            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#content').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, 400, 'easeOutQuint');
                    $('body,html').scrollTop(0);

                    $('#content').html(data);
                },
                error: function (data, request) {

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please include your JS as well.

Comment: and full html also :)

Comment: can anyone help ? :(

Comment: Where is your ng-app?

Comment: not any console errors :)

Comment: <div id="content" style="display: block;" ng-app="CalcQouteModule"> CONTENT AREA </div>

Comment: Are you sure `data.data.collection` is of the correct format? Can you log to `console` and see?

Comment: yes data is in correct format

Comment: Your URl is codrrect? ` var link = '/DashBoard'` ??? Is return correct data???

Comment: when i click on first data comes proper mvc controller called(get proper data and view) but while clicking second time, view not displayed

Answer (score 0):

you probobly forgot to include dependecies in your module initialization saying that you want a new `CalcQouteModule`, which you can do like this:

```
angular.module('CalcQouteModule', [])
```

This code: `angular.module('CalcQouteModule')` will actually try to resolve *existing* module with the name 'CalcQouteModule'. If there isn't one - it will fail.

From angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval):

> Beware that using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.

Here is your code [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Ztm7fUR7ZZI10SU19k7?p=preview):

### Update:

Your `DashboardsController.activate` method is never executed. You can do it in a couple ways. Working example for both options is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/65SxeaB5VOGM2GifEMZ5?p=preview).

#### Quick and dirty way

Inside your ajax callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        // your code...
        $('#content').html(data);
        angular.element('#assemblystatustbl').scope().activate();
    },
    error: function (data, request) { /* ... */ }
});
```

#### Angular way

Use [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) and [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) for animation:

```
<a href='#' ng-click='activate()' ng-show='animate-slide'>Dashboard</a>
```

Most likely this will require to change some code that is out of this answer's scope but this is what you *should* do if you want to use Angular and all it's features rather than manipulating DOM manually and using numerous id and class selectors. 
Here are some piecies of advise:

**First**. You don't want to write you code in `onlick`/`onchange` or subscribe on them using jquery since those are basically out of angular's scope and framework won't track it properly which might cause unpredicted behavior like the one you have with this question. In all cases you can make it work through `ng-click` or `ng-change` bindings.

**Second**. you dont't need to do ajax to fetch html generated on the server. Make your ASP.NET actions return JSON rather than HTML. It will save you from code like this: `$('#content').html(data);` (which is really slow, by the way).

**Thid**. you can request your html from diffent URIs using [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive:

```
<div ng-include="MyCurrentModuleUrl"></div>
```

or templates prerendeed like this in Razor view if your html is small or static:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="@Url.Action("Dashboard")">
    @Html.Action("Dashboard")
</script>
```

Comment: I would still assume that the problem is in module initializatoin, otherwise this would be magic :)

Comment: when run this alone in single page my code works fine, but problem is when, i go for this html in partial view

Comment: can you post that codes also ? codes for loading partials

Comment: is your script inside ajax-reply? do you call `activate` after response received? any js-code would not execute when you grab it via ajax (unless it's jsonp).

Comment: @Aniket updated the answer have a look wheather this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

> Please first assign the `activate` function above, then you call the function below.

```
function DashBoardController($scope, DashBoardFactory) {

  $scope.title = 'DashBoardController';
  $scope.activate = activate;
  $scope.Summary = []; 

  function activate() {
    DashBoardFactory.getSummary()
      .then(
        function(data) {
          console.log(data.data);
          $scope.Summary = data.data.collection;
          //angular.copy(data.data.collection, $scope.Summary);
        }, function(e) {
          alert(e.stautsText);
        });
  }
 **activate();**
}
```

And also you need some changes in your controller assigning method

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'DashBoardController';

    // TODO: replace app with your module name
    angular.module('CalcQouteModule',[]).controller(controllerId,
       ['$scope', '$modal', '$routeParams', '$http', '$route', '$timeout', 'DashBoardFactory']).controller(["$scope", "$modal", "$routeParams", "$http", "$route",
       "$timeout", "DashBoardFactory", function ($scope, $modal, $routeParams, $http, $route, $timeout, DashBoardFactory) {
           $scope.title = 'DashBoardController';
           $scope.activate = activate;
           $scope.Summary = [];

           function activate() {
               DashBoardFactory.getSummary()
                   .then(
                   function (data) {
                       console.log(data.data);
                       $scope.Summary = data.data.collection;
                       //angular.copy(data.data.collection, $scope.Summary);
                   }, function (e) { alert(e.stautsText); });
           }
           activate();

       }])
});
```

### Changes are :-

> - angular.module('CalcQouteModule',[])..........> You have missed the []. It should be needed on model
> - a) If you used rout config, then you should be include `ngRoute` in that model. (version defined)
> - angular.module('CalcQouteModule',[]).controller(controllerId,.......... . I  wrote this code in proper way, please take a look that
> - I  have called the `activate();` function in below that function.
> - **And You should be call the js file in html page**

Comment: when i click on first data comes proper mvc controller called(get proper data and view) but while clicking second time, view not displayed.

Comment: WHy u used `.clk-Menu`.click?? Can you use ng-click??? see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: there are multiple menu links which have class clk-menu. on clicking menu associated item get displayed. In this scenario dashboard get displayed